# Unable to create a variable of an Enumeration

Tags: scala, enumeration

I have created an `Enumeration` as follows:

```
scala> object J extends Enumeration {
     | type J = Value
     | val Fail, Success = Value
     | }
defined object J
```

Question 1 - I tried to create a variable of its type but got the following error. Why?

```
scala> val j:J
<console>:11: error: not found: type J
       val j:J
             ^
<console>:11: error: only classes can have declared but undefined members
       val j:J
           ^
```

Question 2 - I could create a variable as follows. I suppose the `Fail`'s value is actually `0`. How could I print `0`?

```
scala> val j = J.Fail
j: J.Value = Fail

scala> println(j)
Fail
```

Comment: thank you. appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax to assign a type variable, you should do:

```
val j = J
j: J.type = J
```

Regarding the value, Fail and Sucess has no value apart from its own name, if you want to assign a value to them you should use this syntax:

```
object J extends Enumeration {
     type J = Value
     val Fail = Value(0)
     val Success = Value(1)
}
```

Then you can access to it ussing its `id` property

```
scala> j.id
res: Int = 0

scala> j
res: J.Value = Fail
```

Comment: Thanks. Edited my question as it has two parts. Could you please look at the 2nd question as well before I accept your answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry, there you got it, hope it helps

Comment: @ManuChadha; This will not create a variable of type `J` because, in fact, there is no such type. Instead it creates a variable `j` that is a new reference to the `object J`. In other words, now `J` and `j` mean the same thing. They are both references to the singleton object.